# Upload multiple csv files and select same columns from each into one dataframe in R?

Tags: r, loops

I have 92 csv files. Column names are different in each but several columns are the same, and I want to extract those common columns from all the csv files. Following several examples online I have managed to upload all csv files to R environment. My sample code is below.

```
#Set working directory
setwd("File path") #Use your own directory

# Create first example data frame
data1 <- data.frame(id = 1:6,                       
                x1 = c(5, 1, 4, 9, 1, 2),
                x2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))

# Create second example data frame
data2 <- data.frame(id = 7:12,                       
                y1 = c(3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 9),
                y2 = c("a", "x", "a", "x", "a", "x"),
                x2 = c("G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"))

# Create third example data frame
data3 <- data.frame(id = 13:14,                       
                z1 = c(3, 2),
                z2 = c("M", "N"),
                x2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))
```

As you can see, id and x2 columns are common in all three dataframes.

Here are the resulting csv files. Change file path to directory name.

```
write.csv(data1, "File path/data1.csv", # Write first example data
      row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(data2, "File path/data2.csv", # Write second example data
      row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(data3, "File path/data3.csv", # Write third example data
      row.names = FALSE)

#Upload all csv files to R
library("dplyr")                                    
library("plyr")                                     
library("readr")

data_all <- list.files(path = "File path", 
                   pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
lapply(read_csv)
```

How do I extract id and x2 column from all three dataframes into one dataframe? Maybe this can be done before uploading all csv files into the environment?

I have seen many similar examples here, but I cannot figure out how to mix and match all the codes.

Comment: Wait... if its all the same column name, can't you just use ```rbind(df1, df2)```?

Comment: I have 92 files, so I don't want to type rbind (df1, ... , df92)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fake data:

```r
data_all <- list(mtcars[1:2,1:6], mtcars[3:4, 3:8], mtcars[5:7, 5:10])
data_all
# [[1]]
#               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt
# Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875
# [[2]]
#                disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs
# Datsun 710      108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1
# Hornet 4 Drive  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1
# [[3]]
#                   drat   wt  qsec vs am gear
# Hornet Sportabout 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3
# Valiant           2.76 3.46 20.22  1  0    3
# Duster 360        3.21 3.57 15.84  0  0    3
```

Get the names common to all frames:

```r
common <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(data_all, colnames))
common
# [1] "drat" "wt"
```

Use that to combine all data:

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(data_all, `[`, common))
#                   drat    wt
# Mazda RX4         3.90 2.620
# Mazda RX4 Wag     3.90 2.875
# Datsun 710        3.85 2.320
# Hornet 4 Drive    3.08 3.215
# Hornet Sportabout 3.15 3.440
# Valiant           2.76 3.460
# Duster 360        3.21 3.570
```

---

Using your sample data:

```r
data_all <- list(structure(list(id = 1:6, x1 = c(5, 1, 4, 9, 1, 2), x2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)), structure(list(id = 7:12, y1 = c(3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 9), y2 = c("a", "x", "a", "x", "a", "x"), x2 = c("G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)), structure(list(id = c(13L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 14L), z1 = c(3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2), z2 = c("M", "N", "M", "N", "M", "N"), x2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -6L)))
data_all <- list(data1, data2, data3)
common <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(data_all, colnames))
common
# [1] "id" "x2"
do.call(rbind, lapply(data_all, `[`, common))
#    id x2
# 1   1  A
# 2   2  B
# 3   3  C
# 4   4  D
# 5   5  E
# 6   6  F
# 7   7  G
# 8   8  H
# 9   9  I
# 10 10  J
# 11 11  K
# 12 12  L
# 13 13  A
# 14 14  B
# 15 13  C
# 16 14  D
# 17 13  E
# 18 14  F
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but when I apply the common <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(data_all, colnames))
common I get NULL

Comment: That means you have no columns in common among all files. Confirm the mechanism by trying `data_all <- list(data1, data2, data3)` (from your example), run the `Reduce` code, and confirm that you see `c("id", "x2")`.

Comment: When I uploaded the csv files using the loop, it seems that all the columns are in one column now. I have to find where the sep = " " goes in my code.

Answer (score 0):

An approach if you already have the data frames in your local environment (e.g. *data1, data2, data3* etc)

- Get the data frames from names with `get`
- then directly select the desired columns
- finally `rbind` the results with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(rbind, lapply(ls(pattern="data\\d"), \(x) get(x)[c("id", "x2")]))
   id x2
1   1  A
2   2  B
3   3  C
4   4  D
5   5  E
6   6  F
7   7  G
8   8  H
9   9  I
10 10  J
11 11  K
12 12  L
13 13  A
14 14  B
15 13  C
16 14  D
17 13  E
18 14  F
```

Another approach if you want to filter the data directly while reading from file (names "data1.csv" "data2.csv" "data3.csv")

```
Reduce(rbind, lapply(list.files(".", pattern="data\\d.*"), \(x) 
  read.csv(x, header=T)[,c("id", "x2")]))
   id x2
1   1  A
2   2  B
3   3  C
4   4  D
5   5  E
6   6  F
7   7  G
8   8  H
9   9  I
10 10  J
11 11  K
12 12  L
13 13  A
14 14  B
15 13  C
16 14  D
17 13  E
18 14  F
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a near exact implementation of @r2evans answer, using `tidyverse` packages:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

common <- reduce(map(data_all, names), intersect)

bind_rows(data_all) |> 
  select(all_of(common))
```

Here is a simpler implementation that works with this example, but use this with caution. This solution relies on there being no `NA` values in the columns that are in common.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(data_all) |> 
  select(where(~ all(!is.na(.x))))
```

**Output**

```
   id x2
1   1  A
2   2  B
3   3  C
4   4  D
5   5  E
6   6  F
7   7  G
8   8  H
9   9  I
10 10  J
11 11  K
12 12  L
13 13  A
14 14  B
15 13  C
16 14  D
17 13  E
18 14  F
```

Comment: I am sure all of these options will work once my common command doesn't give me NULL.

Comment: @Rnoobie make sure you're using `base::intersect` and not `dplyr::intersect`. They do different things and if you attached the dplyr package you might be masking the base function.